# Magento 2.3.x: How can change the position of STORE-SWITCHER on product details page

Tags: magento2.3, language, product-page, position, store-switcher

I create two store **US**  and **IN**. [image]
 I want to  move this store swither on product details page just in the place of **US-tax rule** check below images.[image]
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?

Comment: @aravind:  use this -  <move element="store_language" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/> .
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: @aravind: please upvote